# Segfault using posix_memalign within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, allocation

I am facing a problem with the posix_memalign right now which is probably caused by a big knot in my brain about pointers and variables.
I haven't worked with C in a while and need to find my way in there again.

I am trying to allocate some memory with posix_memalign and want to use a pointer from a array structs for my address to my allocated memory.

This is basically the method I am using, and I have no idea why this would fail:

```
int init_const(void* data, int alignment, uint64_t size, int offset, DataType type, int stride, int numDomains){

    int i;
    size_t bytesize = 0;
    int errorCode;
    //int elements = 0;

    size_t typesize = dataTypeLength(type);

    bytesize = (size+offset) * typesize;
    //int elements = alignment / typesize;

    data = (void*)malloc(numDomains * sizeof(Datastruct));

    //Allocating memory for array of datastructures
    if(data == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Error: Insufficient memory, can't even malloc array of pointers\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(i=0; i<numDomains; i++){
        Datastruct* structure = (Datastruct*)data+sizeof(Datastruct)*i;
        errorCode =  posix_memalign(structure->a, alignment, bytesize);
        printf("Hallo");
        if (errorCode)
        {
            if (errorCode == EINVAL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "Error: Alignment parameter is not a power of two\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (errorCode == ENOMEM)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "Error: Insufficient memory to fulfill the request\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        if (structure->a == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: posix_memalign failed!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here is my datastruct struct:

```
typedef struct {
    void* a;
} Datastruct;
```

Sadly this causes a segmentation fault at the posix_memalign and I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. It is probably a messed up pointer operation somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 2):

```
man posix_memalign
```

is your friend. You will find there:

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

So it wants the address of the pointer *&structure->a* not the old value *structure->a*.

Comment: ... and it needs a pointer to pointer `structure->a` because that's how it is going to update the pointed-to pointer.  It otherwise would have no way to do so.